# Issues for using Huawei GameTurbo Engine API updateGameAppInfo()

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

I am trying to use Game Turbo Engine API updateGameAppInfo(), but it does not work consistently, sometimes seems it did not send game info to the device. What could be the reason for this? Also, can I use updateGameAppInfo() to send out messages in a batch?

Comment: @Zinna FYI, your posts are being discussed on Meta, feel free to drop by and present your point of view on the problem: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/407802/11407695

Answer (score -2):

Please check to see if in your code, you use updateGameAppInfo() to send out game info. to the device too frequently? If yes, try to revise your design to limit the usage of this API to extend the API call intervals or add wait(...) in between calls. The minimum time required in between these API calls is 10ms. If shorter than that, the 2nd call will be ignored. That can cause the intermittent issue for using updateGameAppInfo() similar to yours.

As for sending out message to device using updateGameAppInfo(), you can only send out one message at a time, batch messages are not supported.

Example for Global game message: in the JSON format:

```
{ "MessageType":0, 
  "PackageName":"xxx.xxx.xxxx.xxx", 
  "AppVersion":"1.0", 
  "ResourceVersion":"1.0",
  "EngineType":2, 
  "EngineVersion":"1.0", 
  "GameType":2, 
  "VulkanSupport":true 
}
```

[Field] MessageType (int)

[Description] Mandatory. The value 0 indicates a global game message.

[Field] PackageName (String)

[Description] Mandatory. It indicates the name of a game package.

[Field] AppVersion (String)

[Description] Mandatory. It indicates the game app version number.

[Field] ResourceVersion (String)

[Description] Optional. It indicates the game resource version number.

[Field] EngineType (byte)

[Description] Optional. It indicates the game engine type.

1: Unity

2: Unreal Engine 4

3: Messiah

4: Cocos2d 200: other game engine [Field] EngineVersion (String)

[Description] Optional. It indicates the version number of the game engine. If EngineType is not set, this parameter can be left empty.

[Field] GameType (byte)

[Description] Optional. It indicates the game type.

1: MOBA (multi-player online battle arena)

2: role playing games (RPG)

3: first-person shooter (FPS)

4: fight technology games (FTG)

5: racing car (RAC) 200: other game category [Field] VulkanSupport (boolean)

[Description] Optional. It indicates whether Vulkan is supported.

For other detailed info. of this API, please refer to: [Link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-References-V5/gamemanager-0000001050123643-V5#EN-US_TOPIC_0000001050123643__section322262018287)